# Insert lecture number and page number of lecture in footline

Tags: latex, beamer

I am dividing a semester's worth of lectures via the \lecture command.
I'd like to have in the footline (among other things) the lecture
number, date, and page number of the current lecture.  I would also
like to use the default style footline, with the black box on the left
and the blue on the right.  So I define a lecture with e.g.

```
\lecture{January 28, 2010}{lecture01}
```

with

```
\title[Lecture \insertlecturenumber{}(\insertlecture)\quad{}Page \insertframenumber]{Course Title}
```

in the preamble, I get an error; it will not accept \insertlecture
there.  If I remove \insertlecture, it does what I want, except that
the page number is counted from the start of the semester, not the
lecture.  Is there any way to do this?  Thank you.

Liam

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally found a solution to this.  First, define

```
\newcounter{lectureframe}
\newcounter{lectureframestart}       % The last frame number of the previous lecture
\newcommand{\lect}[2]{
  \setcounter{lectureframestart}{\value{framenumber}}
  \date{#1}
  \lecture{#1}{#2}
}
```

and then I add a couple lines to the footline template, which is modified from CambridgeUS:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \setcounter{lectureframe}{\value{framenumber}}
  \addtocounter{lectureframe}{-\value{lectureframestart}}
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

with the title:

```
\title[Classname\quad{}Lecture \insertlecturenumber
\quad{}Page \thelectureframe{}]{Classname Lecture}
```

Instead of using `\lecture`, I use `\lect`:

```
\lect{April 13, 2010}{lecture16}
```

Now the title appears appears in the center segment of the footline, and
the date on the right.  This is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to one of my questions.  To reset the 
page number at each section, use

```
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}
```

after (or before) the \lecture command.

Comment: It only solves one of the problems, getting the page number to count from the start of the lecture.  I still don't know how to get the title in the footline; \insertlecture doesn't work.